# doing a updated edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing a module using modal windows, where in the index I am showing all the records, saving data, editing and deleting everything using ajax. Pressing the respective buttons in the row of each record opens the modal window depending on the button. But I would like to press the "edit" button to send the log id to the controller, search the data and return it in the modal window. To send the id to the controller should I place a form on each button?

Answer (score 2):

A traditional non-AJAX edit button that you would typically see in a Rails index page would look something like this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_thing_path(thing) %></td>
```

You would need to do three things to AJAX-ify this:

- change the link_to so that it sends an AJAX request instead,
- get the things_controller#edit method to respond with JSON,
- write some JS that picks up the JSON response from the server, and populates it in the modal's form.

An alternative approach, which might be easier, would be to use UJS as recommended by the Rails core team.  In this case:

- change the link_to to request a JS response
- change the controller's edit method to respond by rendering a JS file
- build a JS file that renders the modal server, side, and then replaces the current modal in your HTML with the newly-built modal form, and then
- reveal the modal in the page

Have a look here in the [Rails Guides (for Rails v4.2)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

To do that I really like to use [Best In place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) its supper simple to use and implement.

there is also a video on how to use it, its a bit old  [302-in-place-editing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing)